# simple function to return number of animations in queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and jQuery. Lately I have taken a fancy to jQuery. Now i have this below snippet of code :

```
$('#move').click(function(){
     $('#block').animate({ 
         'left' : '+=50px' 
     }, 500).this.call(this, get_fx());
});  

function get_fx(){
    var store = console.log($(this).queue('fx').length);
}
```

What the above snippet is supposed to do is on click of the button, move the div by 50 pixels and then calls the function `get_fx()` to check the number of animations attached to `$('#block')`.

Somehow my `call()` function is not working. I basically want to call the `get_fx()` function of `$('#block')`, obviously inside `get_fx()` the this is pointing to `get_fx()` so I have to use `call()` or some other way of changing the context of the this inside `get_fx()` to `$('#block')`.

So to sum up my question how can I make the below work:

```
this.call(this, get_fx());
```

I have referred the jQuery docs while coding but my JS is not so great! I would really appreciate any help .

[fiddle if it helps](http://jsfiddle.net/vn8e5vba/3/)

Thank you.

Alexander .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callbacks to do it:

```
 $('#move').click(function () {
     $('#block').animate({
         'left': '+=50px'
     }, 500, function () {
         console.log($(this).queue().length);
     });
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0bf69yq/)

Comment: I'll vote you up , but i;d preferably like to use call , if thats ok . Thanks though .